# Trek 1.1 Derailleur Hanger

Tags: derailleur

I've got a 2011 Trek 1.1, and my derailleur hanger broke in a crash a few weeks ago. I've tried both a number 5 and number 6 hanger, which are what [WheelsMFG has listed](http://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hanger-manufacturers/?manufacturer=Trek&q=Search+For+Model), but neither seem to fit. There is not any damage to the frame, so I'm at a loss as to why these won't fit. The old derailleur hanger is chewed up, and I can't make out what number it is.

Can anyone suggest a better hanger that I can buy?

Comment: I believe that's what it came with, though I changed everything over to 10 speed Ultegra about a year ago. What's the significance?

Comment: I did not change the hanger when I upgraded.

Comment: Thanks Pete. My current derailleur is 10 speed Ultegra, so I've got no problems there. Are you suggesting that the hanger came as part of the RD-2300? I didn't see it in the diagram.

Comment: I felt guilty about giving you a bum steer before, but have now come up with a link which claims to be the part you need - [W990116](http://www.pedalon.co.uk/acatalog/trek-gear-hanger-990116.html). Further down the page (pink background) there is a pretty complete looking list of Trek models versus hangers. I hope this puts you on the right track, maybe you can find a local supplier?

Comment: @PeteH can you make that an answer please.

Comment: @Mσᶎ that's hardly an answer, simply a nudge in the right direction I hope

Comment: @PeteH but it's an answer to the real question: where can AdoboSeasoning get a hanger that will fit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After calling around to a few different Trek shops and buying several different hangers online, I took my bike to a shop near me that specializes in commuters and things like that.

The mechanic took one look at it, ran to the basement, and came back up with the correct hanger. It is a [Wheels Mfg. #49](http://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hanger-49.html).

I explained to him the trouble I had trying to track down the right hanger, and how it is listed incorrectly on the Wheels Mfg. site. He told me that this hanger in particular is common to a lot of Fujis, so his guess was that they were all made in the same factory, just under different brand names.

Anyway thanks for all the help and research, I'm glad I finally got this resolved.

TL;DR: Wheels Mfg. #49

Comment: tl;dr; should be: take it to your LBS.